# 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configurers'

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am getting **'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulProxyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'configurers'** this error while executing project with **Spring Boot 1.5.4** version.

Its working properly When running same project with spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE. But not able to run on other version.

I have other projects with Spring boot 1.5.4 .So i cant update my spring boot version on other pc. Any other solution for this to run on other pc?

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.5.RELEASE
 

com.example
test-api
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
test-api

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: To include Zuul in your project, use the starter with a group ID of org.springframework.cloud and a artifact ID of spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul.  


   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
According to the documentation, you need the org.springframework.cloud dependencies to make it work.

Comment: included everything..please check my pom file in question